# how to implement my button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am making a school based project, and it has to be done in javascript and jquery. However these languages are quite new to me, so it's a bit of difficulty for me. My question: how can I append my button so it can submit the form that I have filled out? 
a fiddle for u to get an idea of it. I want my button to be placed next to the green one, please do not mind the red minus button. that's something in progress.  jsfiddle.net/DanDy/hqy73b0h

underneath is the code that I want to implement:

```
function submitCSMBtn(target, i) {
  var submitBtn = $('<button/>', {
 'class': 'btn btn-info fa fa-download',
 'type': 'submit',
 });

return submitBtn;
}
```

all the code in case you need to review it as a whole:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var id = 0;
  var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
   'class': 'btn btn-success',
   'id': 'addOpdracht'
}).on('click', function(){
    $('form').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
    id++;
}).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');

$('form').append(addOpdracht);
 })



function getAddBtn(target, i){
  var addBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-primary'
            }).on('click', function(){
              $(target).append(getWordPartInput(i));
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
            console.log(target);
return addBtn;
 }

 function getExerciseBlock(i){
  var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
 'id': i,
 'class': 'col-md-12, eBlock'
 });

  $(eBlock).append(getAudioBtn(i), getWordInput(i), getWordPartInput(i), 
getAddBtn(eBlock, i));

return eBlock;
 }


function getAudioBtn(id, cValue){
 cValue = cValue || '';
 var audioBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-primary'
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>');
 return audioBtn;
   }


  function getWordInput(id, cValue){
    cValue = cValue || '';
    var wInput = $('<input/>', {
                'class': 'form-group form-control',
                'type': 'text',
                'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[]',
                'placeholder': 'Exercise',
                'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput'
            })
    return wInput;
  }


function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
 cValue = cValue || '';
 var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
                  'class': 'form-group form-control',
                  'type': 'text',
                  'value': cValue,
                  'placeholder': 'Syllables',
                  'id': 'SyllablesGetWordPartInput'
              });
 return wpInput;
   }

function submitCSMBtn(target, i) {
 var submitBtn = $('<button/>', {
'class': 'btn btn-info fa fa-download',
'type': 'submit',
});

 return submitBtn;
  }
```

I am trying to add my submit button so it will submit the form (has to go to JSON, maybe that will have a different approach... just giving extra info). from what I know I should use something with the command .on('click', function()) if not mistaken, and it should go in my eBlock if not mistaken either, but whenever I try this it will result in me losing functionality (ea, adding inputs etc. but I keep the layout). I have been looking around however to get a clear explaination of the on('click') function because it's new to me. what I have found was http://api.jquery.com/on/
not sure if this is the same. So if you guys could help me along, that would be great!

EDIT: my HTML code aswell. Apparentely that's needed too, sorry.
NOTE: I just took the code from body to body instead of putting the useless code in it aswell.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h2 id="exerciseTitleCMS" class="col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-6">CMS</h2>
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
                                    <h2>
                                        <select class="languageSelector form-control required" id="languageSelector" ></select>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>      <!-- end of panel-heading -->
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="jumbotron" id="mainList">
                        <form class="container-fluid" action="#" method="POST" required>

                        </form>
                    </div> 
                </div>      <!-- end of panel-body -->          
            </div>      <!-- end panel-primary -->
        </div>      <!--end panel-group -->
    </div>  <!-- end of container-->
 </body>
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: sure :) you want me to just edit my post and place it into it ?

Comment: Yes, without the HTML is pretty hard to see what is going on

Comment: Placed it, i hope you don't mind I took the body to body part (as that's most likely what ur looking for).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('<button></button>')
  .addClass('btn-class')
  .attr('type', 'submit')
  .appendTo('form-selector');
```

But rather than dynamically adding the submit button, you could also put the button in the HTML form, and then programmatically showing it on some event:

*With jQuery:*

```js
$(function() {
  $('#submit_button').hide();
  
  $('#show_submit_button').on('click', function() {
    $('#submit_button').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='my_form' class='my_form_class'>
  <input type='submit' id='submit_button' />
</form>

<button id='show_submit_button'>Show submit button!</button>
```

*Or with CSS (and jQuery):*

```js
$(function() {
  $('#toggle_submit_button').on('click', function() {
    $('#submit_button').toggleClass('hidden_submit_buttton shown_submit_button');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden_submit_button {
  display: none;
 }
 .shown_submit_button {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='my_form' class='my_form_class'>
  <input type='submit' id='submit_button' class='hidden_submit_button' />
</form>

<button id='toggle_submit_button'>Show/Hide submit button!</button>
```

Comment: You sir, nailed it in every possible way. Quick question, is it possible to make one button like the "show/hide" one that turns into a submit button or isn't this possible because u will have to change the button from outside the form to inside the form?

Comment: It is possible, but I wouldn't recommend doing that, because they're two completely different buttons with completely different actions. But if you want, you could use `add/removeClass` or `attr` and such to change the button's properties

Comment: well, i'll go with ur knowledge and take this for granted. I appreciate the help and effort you put into this! So thank you very much @qjnr

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.
There are few ways to append object.

instead of:

```
function submitCSMBtn(target, i) {
  var submitBtn = $('<button/>', {
 'class': 'btn btn-info fa fa-download',
 'type': 'submit',
 });

return submitBtn;
}
```

Most easiest way is you can append just plain html string:

```
var submitBtn = '<button class=\'btn btn-info fa fa-download\' type=\'submit\'><button />';

//then you can append the html string to element you want to append:
$('#your_element_ID').append(submitBtn);
```

Comment: I tried ur code, but it doesn't seem to work with the code I have.

Comment: You need to escape the single-quotes inside the HTML-string